# !heap failed. Invalid type information for ntdll!_HEAP_ENTRY

Tags: debugging, heap-memory, windbg

I'm trying to dump heap information from full dump memory file sitting on Windows Server 2003 SP2 x86. Dump was created for 32-bit mixed (native/clr) application which was running on Windows Server 2003 SP2 x64 machine.

From the following windbg log I understand that loaded ntdll.dll image is incorrect and does not correspond to ntdll.pdb symbols. I have tried to specify the location to ntdll.dll from the target machine but windbg still shows that the module is loaded from the standard location (c:\windows\system32).

What did I do wrong? How to force windbg to load correct version of `ntdll`?

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

[ ... skipped ... ]

0:042> vertarget
Windows Server 2003 Version 3790 (Service Pack 2) MP (4 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
kernel32.dll version: 5.2.3790.4480 (srv03_sp2_gdr.090321-1244)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Wed Mar 16 16:36:10.000 2011 (GMT-5)
System Uptime: 17 days 10:34:26.068
Process Uptime: 1 days 15:19:14.000
  Kernel time: 0 days 1:24:01.000
  User time: 0 days 22:07:58.000

0:042> .sympath
Symbol search path is: C:\mscordacwks\v2.0.50727.3615;C:\__exe;SRV*C\Symbols*http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols;SRV*c:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;SRV*C:\Symbols*http://source.msdn.microsoft.com/symbols

0:042> .exepath
Executable image search path is: C:\__exe;C:\__target\Windows\SysWOW64;

0:042> .reload

[ ... skipped ... ]

0:042> .reload /u ntdll.dll
Unloaded ntdll.dll
0:042> .reload /v /f ntdll.dll
AddImage: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll // why is it still c:\windows\system32
 DllBase  = 7d600000
 Size     = 000f0000
 Checksum = 000c371a
 TimeDateStamp = 4cc1831e

0:042> lm
[ ... skipped ... ]
7d600000 7d6f0000   ntdll      (pdb symbols) c:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\9ED8E09C6723448380648C4456726AEF2\wntdll.pdb

0:042> !heap 
*************************************************************************
***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols                 ***
[ ... skipped ... ]
***    Type referenced: ntdll!_HEAP_ENTRY                             ***
*************************************************************************
Invalid type information 

0:042> lmi vm ntdll
start    end        module name
7d600000 7d6f0000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          ntdll.dll
    Symbol file: c:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\9ED8E09C6723448380648C4456726AEF2\wntdll.pdb
    Image path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
    Image name: ntdll.dll
    Timestamp:        Fri Oct 22 07:27:10 2010 (4CC1831E)
    CheckSum:         000C371A
    ImageSize:        000F0000
    File version:     5.2.3790.4789 // this is correct and 
    Product version:  5.2.3790.4789 // does correspond to target computer
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
    InternalName:     ntdll.dll
    OriginalFilename: ntdll.dll
    ProductVersion:   5.2.3790.4789
    FileVersion:      5.2.3790.4789 (srv03_sp2_gdr.101019-0340)
    FileDescription:  NT Layer DLL
    LegalCopyright:   c Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

UPDATE:

I moved a little bit further in my issue. I managed to connect to the live process on the customers side and tried to 
investigate heap (heap -s) there and basically I got the same result.

```
(1520.7c4): Wake debugger - code 80000007 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00327d50 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=0030b428 edi=002debe4
eip=7d61c876 esp=002df008 ebp=002df06c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll -
ntdll!ZwReadFile+0x15:
7d61c876 c22400          ret     24h
0:000> !heap -s
*************************************************************************
***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols                 ***
*** [...skipped...]                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: ntdll!_HEAP_ENTRY                             ***
*************************************************************************
Invalid type information
0:000> .reload
Reloading current modules
................................................................
....................................
0:000> !heap -s
*************************************************************************
***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols                 ***
*** [...skipped...]                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: ntdll!_HEAP_ENTRY                             ***
*************************************************************************
Invalid type information
```

I think I have a problem similar to one mentioned in this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959207.
Environment and problem seem to be the same but dll versions are different, so it is not the solution for me.

I think I have to escalate this problem to Microsoft.

Does anybody know where I should go with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution appears to be easy but not obvious.

- I found a wntdll.pdb slightly bigger than mine which contains required symbols and reloaded it with command `.reload /f /i ntdll.dll`
- and I take the previous build of windbg 6.11.0001.404, in the current one 6.12.0002.633 `!heap` command still does not work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

This could happen if dump was created with 64 bit tools. There is good information on [Tess's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx) that explains the reason why bitness of the dump matters.

Comment: The dump is 32 bit. I can see it trying to switch it to 32 bit mode in windbg.

<pre><code>
0:042> .load wow64exts
0:042> !sw
!wow64exts.sw : command invalid on non-64bit target
</code></pre>

Maybe this is the reason (32 bits dump created on 64 bits system) why I cannot load ntdll.dll from another location.

Comment: Then it is something else. You can confirm the type of modules with !lmi (you were using lmi without !, this is different command). !lmi will dump Machine Type, which would be either I386 or X64. In your case you should expect "!lmi ntdll.dll" would print I386.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the type _HEAP_ENTRY is not included in the pdb of 2003 SP2 ntdll.dll
Microsoft released a hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959207, but you seem to have a later ntdll version.