# !heap failed (Invalid type information)

Tags: debugging, heap-memory, windbg

OS: Windows 10 x64 1909

target process: lec06_1.exe (32bit)

```
0:003> !heap
Invalid type information

0:003> dt ntdll!_HEAP
Symbol ntdll!_HEAP not found.

0:003> dt ntdll!_HEAP_ENTRY
Symbol ntdll!_HEAP_ENTRY not found.


0:003> lm
start    end        module name
001c0000 001c6000   lec06_1    (deferred)             
706e0000 707ce000   MSVCR120   (deferred)             
74f70000 75050000   KERNEL32   (deferred)             
759c0000 75bbc000   KERNELBASE   (deferred)             
77410000 775aa000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\wntdll.pdb\D85FCE08D56038E2C69B69F29E11B5EE1\wntdll.pdb
```

This alternative didn't work on me.

```
.symfix
.reload
```

What should I do now? plz..

Comment: I had the same issue and managed to *fix* it using this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5541038/52598). Not a good solution but I couldn't find a better one. It would be nice if someone could post a definitive solution.

Comment: 32 Bit symbols seem to be broken at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when using the `!peb` extension in WinDbg on Windows 10 (version 1909, x64):

```
0:000> !peb
PEB at 0115d000
error 3 InitTypeRead( nt!_PEB at 0115d000)...
```

The wntdll.pdb file with pdb signature *D85FCE08D56038E2C69B69F29E11B5EE1* doesn't contain any type information. **This is a problem which can only be solved by Microsoft**.

However, I found a workaround which seems to be working for my case:

- find an older version of wntdll.pdb which still contains the type information (I used the .pdb with signature *50D4EDAA6B13688D234F3E853C20E0A31* and checked that the type information exist with the cvdump tool from https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-pdb)
- unload the symbols in windbg with `.reload /u` if still loaded
- rename the current .pdb in the *D85FCE08D56038E2C69B69F29E11B5EE1* folder
- copy (not move!) the older wntdll.pdb in the *D85FCE08D56038E2C69B69F29E11B5EE1* folder
- download the chkmatch tool from http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html
- run the chkmatch tool as follows (make sure to replace [symbolpath] with the symbol cache directory you're using)

  ```
  chkmatch -m C:\windows\syswow64\ntdll.dll [symbolpath]\wntdll.pdb\D85FCE08D56038E2C69B69F29E11B5EE1\wntdll.pdb
  ```
- reload the symbols in windbg with `.reload`
- check if the missing type information are available now (e.g. in your case with `dt ntdll!_HEAP` or `!heap`

With this approach I was able to get the process environment block information I was missing. I hope that it will work in your case too.